# Why is there an error if there is a return inside the else, and if there is a return outside the for, isn't there an error?

Tags: java

It's a code to get a common divisor. The first code fails and the second code does not(This method must return a result of type int). I really want to know why....

If we don't have a common divisor, we want to return -1.

```
public class aaa{
   public static int function(int a, int b){
         for(int a = 1; i <= a; i++){
             if ( a % i == 0){ 
                 b--;
             }if ( b == 0) {
                 return i;
             }else {
                 return -1;
             }
         }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
          system.out.println("The 5th common measure of 1000 is" + fuction(1000, 5));
   }
}
```

```
public class aaa{
   public static int function(int a, int b){
         for(int a = 1; i <= a; i++){
             if ( a % i == 0){ 
                 b--;
             }if ( b == 0) {
                 return i;
             }
         } return -1;
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
          system.out.println("The 5th common measure of 1000 is" + fuction(1000, 5));
   }
}
```

Comment: What will your function return if `a` is less than `1`? No `return` will ever be hit.

Comment: In the `b--` case int he first snippet there is no `return`, the compiler cannot whether or not a method invocation will always hit one of the other two cases eventually.

Comment: Try to ask yourself "Do all possible paths return some value?"

Comment: Neither of these programs makes sense, though, because your loop variable is `a` rather than `i`, and `i` is never defined.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has 2 separate bugs in it which makes your question moot.

### Why you get this error

As I mentioned, your method doesn't in any way calculate divisors so perhaps you shouldn't be focused on this in the first place. But, hey, you asked.

> (This method must return a result of type int). I really want to know why....

You look at your code, your brain makes a few assumptions (for example, `a` and `b` are both obviously more than 1, who would ask for the greatest common divisor of 1, right? Or even worse, 0?) - and then goes: Wha? This method obviously always returns, clearly. What the heck is the compiler on about?

But that's not how a computer works. That info about 'a cannot, clearly, ever be below 2' isn't written anywhere, so the compiler does not assume it.

If `a` is 0, then no `return` statement is ever executed, so what should this method do then? *That* is what the compiler is complaining about.

### Your code doesn't do what you think it does

Your code has a bug in it, clearly you meant to write `for (int i = 1`, not `for (int a = 1`) - that is a separate issue. Code can have more than a single problem, of course.

A second more important issue is that your code doesn't work at all in the first place: Your loop never loops - it enters once (even if you fix the above problem), with `i` being 1, and then:

- if `a % 1` is 0, which it will always be, decrement `b` (why? This is wrong)
- Then just `return false` - stop the entire method.

You never even loop.

Comment: I think the point of the exercise is to find f(a,b) which is the b'th measure of a, not the common divisor of a and b. In that light, decrementing b makes sense, and I think the second version of the program may actually work.